# gcloud auth not working inside dockerfile

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dockerfile

I have made a multistage dockerfile that installs my npm packes and then tries to deploy them to gcp

Issue is when I run my deploy it tells me it can't open the configuration file and I don't have a active account selected

```
WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.19.0-alpine3.9 AS build

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

FROM google/cloud-sdk

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app /app

RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /app/firebase-service-account.json
RUN gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT
RUN gcloud config set account service-account-email@service-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I also wrote a bash script to build and deploy my cloud function

```
#! /bin/sh

docker build . -f deploy-functions.dockerfile -t cloud-functions-deploy

docker run cloud-functions-deploy gcloud functions deploy event-log-trigger \
--project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
--entry-point eventLogBuilder \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update \
--trigger-resource projects/${GCP_PROJECT_ID}/databases/\(default\)/documents/events/\{eventId\} \
--region=${GCP_REGION} --stage-bucket=${STAGE_BUCKET} --runtime nodejs10
```

In my first bash script I didn't have the `--project` flag but needed to add it becase it was saying the command didn't have a project. It does seem that warning is correct and its unable to open  the `config_default` file even though I am running everything as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this issue by creating an `entrypoint.sh` file

```sh
# entrypoint.sh
# Set your env variables GCP_PROJECT_ID, STAGE_BUCKET, GCP_REGION, ...
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /app/firebase-service-account.json
gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
# your deploy command
gcloud functions deploy event-log-trigger \
--entry-point eventLogBuilder \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update \
--trigger-resource projects/${GCP_PROJECT_ID}/databases/\(default\)/documents/events/\{eventId\} \
--region=${GCP_REGION} --stage-bucket=${STAGE_BUCKET} --runtime nodejs10
```

And setting this info in the Dockerfile

```
# previous stage ... 
FROM google/cloud-sdk

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app /app

RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

> It seems that the commands do not persist after the image is formed.

```
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /app/firebase-service-account.json
RUN gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT
RUN gcloud config set account service-account-email@service-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I checked this by running the command

```
docker run cloud-functions-deploy gcloud config list
```

Answer (score 0):

For the authentication, instead of doing this

```
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /app/firebase-service-account.json
```

Simply define a env var

```
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/firebase-service-account.json
```

For the project and the account, you can add it in params of your gcloud calls (with `--project` and `--account` flags).